Get change notifications teams presence using Microsoft Graph API without delegated permissions
I am working on a application which needs ms teams change notifications for presence to update the frontend. The issue is this application will open in another application as an IFRAME, I have tried to implement login using in IFRAME but MSAL-REACT gives error.
Is there any way, I can get the teams presence change notifications without user interaction because I can't implement login within IFRAME as MSAL-REACT doesn't support it.
Also through Application permissions, change notification not supported yet.

Tried MSAL-REACT authentication within IFRAME but failed.


Sounds as if you're working on behalf of a user. How about making the request with application permissions instead?

You cannot perform change subscriptions specially user presence change with Application level permissions.

Issue is resolved and I have used Popup method within myapp which is opening as an Iframe to resolve this issue with MSAL react.
